# Show a JDialog with MouseEnter event

Tags: java, swing, popup, jtable

I am using  a `JTable`, I my first column I have an image, I would like that when I pass the mouse over it looks more enlarged, I mean to open a kind of a window with a larger picture.
I am using a custom model, the cell works as `JLabel`.

I tried this :

```
private void jLabel1MouseEntered(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) { 
     NewJDialog c = new NewJDialog(this, rootPaneCheckingEnabled);
     c.setVisible(true);   
}
```

this is my DefaultTableCellRenderer:

```
public class IconCellRenderer extends DefaultTableCellRenderer {


    public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column) {
        if (value instanceof JLabel) {
            JLabel label = (JLabel) value;
            label.setOpaque(true);
            fillColor(table, label, isSelected);        
            return label;
        } else {
            return super.getTableCellRendererComponent(table, value, isSelected, hasFocus, row, column);
        }
    }


    public void fillColor(JTable t, JLabel l, boolean isSelected) {
        if (isSelected) {
           l.setBackground(t.getSelectionBackground());
           l.setForeground(t.getSelectionForeground());

           l.setBackground(new Color(255, 255, 200));
        } else {
            l.setBackground(t.getBackground());
            l.setForeground(t.getForeground());
        }
    }

}
```

I know it works but my question is: how to do it with a specific `JTable` cell?

Comment: Use a tool tip in the cell renderer.  BTW - You forgot to ask a question.

Comment: What did u try? What did u get? Give some code, so that we can help you

Comment: *"how to do it with a specific `JTable` cell?"*  Again, why not *use a tool tip in the cell renderer*?

Comment: Andrew Thompson ,I have understood that it is to show a text.

Comment: JLabel is Opaque(true) by default

Comment: Renderer is simple wrong, search here more about